# Send value to ValueConverter

Tags: c#, silverlight, ivalueconverter

I have this ValueConverter:

```
public class LabelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value,
                          Type targetType,
                          object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        return ApplicationSettings.getTranstaltion(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

It is used to convert some labels according to the selected language. The value that should be passed in is the labelName which is then looked up in the database. Then the propper translation is chosen and sent back. Here are the two attempts that I have used but which both failed:

```
 <telerik:ChartLegend Header="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LabelConverter},
                              ConverterParameter='lblLegend'}"
                              x:Name="ChartLegend1"
                              />

<telerik:ChartLegend Header="{Binding ElementName=ChartLegend1, Path=Tag
                              Converter={StaticResource LabelConverter}"
                              x:Name="ChartLegend1"
                              Tag="lblLegend"
                              />
```

Any help?

Comment: The way you are trying to implement it looks awkward. 
I would either choose an attached property to achieve the same thing or override some basic controls (textblock etc) and catch the onloaded event or something to do the translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind is to check try adding the binding mode explicitly with `Mode=TwoWay`.

[Edit]
Additionally you should check if check if `ApplicationSettings.getTranstaltion()` throws an exception that is silently choked by Silverlight. Lastly, could `value` ever be **null**? In that case value.ToString() might throw an exception.

Silverlight often handles exceptions silently without the user noticing it (or due to your Visual Studio exception  settings), so in both of the latter cases the converter might not do something without ever presenting an exception to you.

Comment: I so love when I forget this damn mode -_-

Thanks a lot! I will accept it in 5 minutes when SO allows it :)

Comment: The value can't be null because I am always explicitly specifying the value so this shouldn't be a concerne... thanks again one more time:)

Comment: Hello Ivan, I had just edited my post while you already had commented. :-) I'm glad I could help you!